# How do I use tkinter's separator (or another tool) here?

Tags: python, tkinter, sudoku

I'm trying to create my own Sudoku, and I managed to write the code providing a perfect random generator of Sudoku grid.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3jOn.png)
I get this:

And i want to create separators to canvass the grid (to see clearly 9 cases each grouping 9 number), perhaps using the ttk.Separator function. But I can't manage to "grid" it.. Plus I would need several of them. How should I do ?

If useful, there is the code which implements my Entry cases. I have a big function that assigns each entry a number using the variables v, column and row.

```
class Input():
    def __init__(self, row, column):
    global v
    v = StringVar()
    self.row = row
    self.column = column
    self.entry = Entry(root, text=v, width=2, justify="center", insertofftime=0, font="Century 20").grid(
        row=row+1, column=column+1, ipadx=13, ipady=13, padx=1, pady=1)

def value_def(self, deflt):
    v.set(deflt)
```

Comment: the separator must be in an individual grid, so there is no way to do this without changing your actual grid.

Comment: You mean putting my sudoku columns in column 1,2,3 5,6,7 9,10,11 on the grid, so that I have empty column that I can use ? Already done putting empty frames in those empty columns, the new frames position themselves in the column already used, as if there were no empty column available

Comment: Then specify the width and height (background color as well) of those frames, otherwise they are of zero size.

Comment: when you use grid, the size of the rows and columns are the size of larger the element in this rows/columns. If you use an empty frame in a grid, the frame will occupy no space and so the grid, unless you specify its size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a separator, use a frame with a black background, and use padding to leave spaces between the rows and columns.

Here's an example that illustrates the technique. First I create a class to define one 3x3 grid, and then create a 3x3 grid of class instances. This is by no means the only way to solve this problem, but it shows what it looks like when you add space between items with `grid`.

```
import tkinter as tk

class SmallGrid(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, background="black")
        self.entries = {}

        self.grid_rowconfigure((0,1,2), weight=1, uniform="equal")
        self.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2), weight=1, uniform="equal")

        for row in (0, 1, 2):
            for column in (0, 1, 2):
                entry = tk.Entry(self, width=2, borderwidth=0)
                entry.grid(row=row, column=column, padx=2, pady=2, sticky="nsew")
                self.entries[row,column] = entry

root = tk.Tk()

root.grid_rowconfigure((0,1,2), weight=1, uniform="equql")
root.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2), weight=1, uniform="equal")

groups = {}
for row in (0, 1, 2):
    for column in (0, 1, 2):
        group = SmallGrid(root)
        group.grid(row=row, column=column, padx=2, pady=2)
        groups[row, column] = group

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]